# android - how to open the embed url's using webview

Tags: android, webview

In my application i want to display the directions between two geo points using embed url of Google maps in webview. But it's not working.In browser it's showing the directions page but in device its showing the sign page.

```
Code:
```

public class android_testing extends Activity
{

```
public WebView webview;     
protected ProgressDialog web_pd;
final Handler rb_web_pd_Handler = new Handler();    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);                   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv_direction);  
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    web_pd = ProgressDialog.show(android_testing.this, "", "Please wait...", true);
    Thread t = new Thread() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {               
            rb_web_pd_Handler.post(checked_LoginResp);
        }                                               
    };
    t.start();

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });
    float source_lat = 17.493133f;
    float source_long = 78.398438f;
    float dest_lat = 17.444992f;
    float dest_long = 78.379898f;
    String page_url ="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+"&saddr="+source_lat+","+source_long+"&output=embed";             
    System.out.println("URL:"+page_url);       
    webview.loadUrl(page_url);      
}

 final Runnable checked_LoginResp = new Runnable()
 {
     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
             {
                 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                 {
                     if(progress == 100)
                     {
                         web_pd.dismiss();  
                     }
                 }
             });
         } 
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }      
 };          }
```

In Browser

[image]

But in device

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To simply display the google map with 2 locations no need to use separate activity and webview in that, simply call like below code

```
float source_lat = 17.493133f;
    float source_long = 78.398438f;
    float dest_lat = 17.444992f;
    float dest_long = 78.379898f;

String sourcelatitudeString=source_lat.toString();
String sourcelongitudeString=source_long.toString();


Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+sourcelatitudeString+","+sourcelongitudeString+"&daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+""));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: One more thing have you generated map key to display maps?

Comment: Yes, I agree but i want to display it in webview. is it possible?

Comment: In log is not showing any problem? that's why i am not getting it.